# Using AVT Vimba SDK in QT Creator C++

Tags: c++, qt, libraries

I would like to write simple program to capture images with Allied Vision Technologies Camera using QT Creator in C++. The problem is I have some errors which I don't understand. I created a simple QT console application. I added external libraries to the project. (Right click on project -> add libraries, external libraries, AVTVimba.lib, and include folder with *.h files).

My .pro file:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = AVT3
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaCPP/Lib/Win64/ -lVimbaCPP
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaCPP/Lib/Win64/ -lVimbaCPPd

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaCPP/Include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaCPP/Include

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaCPP/Lib/Win64/libVimbaCPP.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaCPP/Lib/Win64/libVimbaCPPd.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaCPP/Lib/Win64/VimbaCPP.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaCPP/Lib/Win64/VimbaCPPd.lib

INCLUDEPATH +="D:\Programy\AVTVimba_1.3"

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaC/Lib/Win64/ -lVimbaC
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaC/Lib/Win64/ -lVimbaCd

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaC/Include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaC/Include

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaC/Lib/Win64/libVimbaC.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaC/Lib/Win64/libVimbaCd.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaC/Lib/Win64/VimbaC.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Programy/AVTVimba_1.3/VimbaC/Lib/Win64/VimbaCd.lib
```

Everything seems to be fine, I can include header file VimbaCPP.h to my project and use AVT::VmbAPI namespace and don't have any compile errors. In order to test if everything works fine I tried to copy listing from AVT CPP Manual.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "VimbaCPP.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace AVT::VmbAPI;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    cout<<"123"<<endl;

    CameraPtrVector cameras;

   // VimbaSystem &system = VimbaSystem::GetInstance();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The code above compiles and runs without any problems. CameraPtrVector is a part of AVT::VmbAPI namespace so I assume that libraries are linked correctly. Now when I uncomment the next line: "VimbaSystem &system..." my program doesn't work and is executed with code -1073741510. I can't find the source of this problem. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I am also working on this problem these days. It seems that the best solution is using Pymba and PyQT instead. Or you can use VS2010 as the example does. Pymba: https://github.com/morefigs/pymba

Comment: I tried using .NET libraries in VS and everything works fine so I will develop my app in it.